# Can I create a SOAP/JMS service without forcing the consumer to add the MQ maker's library?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, jms, cxf

I was testing the SOAP over JMS Web Services built with Apache CXF. In particular, I was following the ["jms_specs_demo"](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jms_spec_demo): a WSDL-fist sample describing the consumer required call, the SOAP service implementation and the Queue needed for the message persistence.

The client call is equals to a SOAP over HTTP call (the endpoint is on the WSDL file). However, the JMS JNDI address uses the MQ maker's library (org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory) and it's also required on the client:

```
<soap:address location="jms:jndi:dynamicQueues/test.cxf.jmstransport.queue?jndiInitialContextFactory=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;jndiConnectionFactoryName=ConnectionFactory&amp;jndiURL=tcp://localhost:61616"/>
```

I have built an independent client for testing it:

```
JMSGreeterService service = new JMSGreeterService();
JMSGreeterPortType greeter = service.getGreeterPort();

greeter.greetMeOneWay("hello World");
```

But effectively, this code only works if the ApacheMQ dependency is added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    <version>5.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to create a SOAP over JMS service without needing to add the MQ maker's library (JAR) on the consumer? I thought JMS API would manage the transport and to push the message into the remote queue without extra libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, No. The JMS API is in and of itself just that - an API that defines the contracts that JMS objects must fulfil. See the [javadoc for the JMS API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html).

To actually use JMS, your client needs to use a concrete implementation of the JMS API (known as the JMS provider), which is what you are doing by using the activemq-broker library.